# In SQL Server, for choosing hierarchical data, which is typically faster: a while loop with fast exit, or a rank and filter operation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlperformance

I have a series of tables representing objects and their properties in a SQL server DB, roughly of the form

Objects:

```
ObjectId    ParentObjectId
1           null
2           1
3           2
...
10          9
```

Properties:

```
PropertyId    PropertyName    PropertyValue
1             Name            Bob
2             City            New York
```

Object-Property relationships

```
Id            ObjectId       PropertyId
1             10             1
2             5              2
```

Since `10` is a descendant of `5`, in the example above, it would be named Bob and in New York.

The process to identify this goes:

- Identify the object hierarchy, including the consumption order
- Then one of the below:

  - Use a WHILE LOOP to retrieve the first object that has the property. This involves a lot of `SELECT TOP 1 <Items> FROM ObjectPropertyRelations WHERE ObjectId = @CurrentId` actions.
  - Use an inner join between the identified hierarchy order, the object-property relationship table and the properties table, ranking, and retrieve the highest rank.

Both of these have performance implications for non-trivial numbers of properties. As near as I can tell, if most of the time the property is on the object in question, the while loop will probably win, whereas if most of the time it is on an ancestor, the inner join probably will. However I'm hoping someone can either confirm this, or disprove it. There are, after all, plenty of articles out there demonstrating WHILE as better than cursors, but I have yet to see one comparing it vs `RANK() OVER (...)` approaches.

It might be worth bearing in mind that in my actual data, an object can have two kinds of inheritance, one of "templates" (which is close to class-based inheritance) and one of "parent" as above, (which is closer to obtaining properties from context).

Comment: You don't need a while loop for the first design. A recursive common table expression will do that in a single query - much more efficient then a while loop

Comment: Your suggested techniques look questionable at best - the standard approach to query hierarchical data is a recursive query. If you give some example code behind your "Identify the object hierarchy" and so on so we know what you're trying to do, we may be able to suggest a better solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RECURSIVE in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840998/recursive-in-sql)